# React Native Modal Not Closing

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I'm overlaying the following [Modal](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html) component in my iOS app while waiting for several async requests to come back.

```
<Modal transparent={true} visible={this.state.visible}>
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <ActivityIndicator color="white" size="large"/>
    </View>
</Modal>
```

this.state.visible is set to false once all the requests have returned. However, about 50% of the time the modal remains on the screen indefinitely, even after the requests have come back. I've logged this.state.visible at the top of my render function and it is false as expected, yet the modal does not disappear. Any thoughts as to why this may be happening?

Comment: Have you found any solutions ? It seems issue still exists

Comment: Have you found any solutions?

Comment: Can you post the entire code of the file?

Comment: You do this.setState in the

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps it was the same problem I'm facing here.

I get this problem when closing one modal and opening another, some people are getting this with a modal and an alert...

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10471

For now, the solution is a timeout before the action (600ms should solve it).

Comment: That's something that is very likely to change in many different situations. In my case, using `redux-saga` I set `yield delay(600)` before the action that changes the modal visibility.

If you are just setting the `state` you could do something like `setTimeout(() => this.setState({ visible: true }), 600)`.

But I honestly think you should take a look your code in general, perhaps there is a better way.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution for now, before showing the dialog again, first, make it invisible with time delay, then show the dialog again

```
this.setState({
    showPopUp: false,
  }, () => {
    let timer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        showPopUp: true,
      });
    }, 300);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the react-native-paper modal.

```
import { Modal } from 'react-native-paper';
```